# What are phrases without explicit meanings called?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

Do we have a name for those phrases without explicit meanings? At first look, they can't make much sense.

For instance,
'*put up with*',
'*put me through*',
'*get to (something)*', 
etc.

Comment: [Idiom](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiom): an expression that cannot be understood from the meanings of its separate words but that has a separate meaning of its own (Merriam-Webster)

Comment: @Rathony +1 I'd also upvote that as an answer.

Comment: @Lawrence Thanks for your comment, but I don't think this question belongs on ELU.

Comment: @Rathony The term 'phrasal verb' is not only useful for language learners.  It is a term that native speakers of English may never have come across before, and so it arguably needs to be here. The other thing is that it is not easy to reverse-look up this term. So maybe this Q would be useful here after all.

Comment: All of your example phrases have explicit meanings, just not ones that can be determined by analyzing the words of the phrases separately. All your examples are verb phrases, but many other types of phrases cannot be understood without context outside the sentences they contain.

Comment: @JOSH Yes. And your point?

Comment: @deadrat - that the examples are all phrasal verbs.

Comment: Can you please name some examples of words that do have explicit meanings. Because no word in any language has any meaning other than the one (or fifty) that a rather random bunch of folks happen to rather randomly agree to give it at that one moment in time. "Put up with" might not make much sense at first look, but neither does "put".

Answer (score 0):

I think the  expression you are looking for is ***[phrasal verb](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/phrasal-verb)***:

> - Phrasal verbs are verb phrases that have idiomatic meanings. Their meaning is not obvious from the individual words that make up the phrase.

The Free Dictionary

> - a phrase that consists of a verb with a preposition or adverb or both, the meaning of which is different from the meaning of its separate parts:
>
>   - *"Pay for", "work out", and "make up for" are all phrasal verbs*.

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: @AlanCarmack - thank you, I forgot where I had taken that from, will add it soon.